# Laravel Validation on multiple string options

Tags: laravel, validation, constants

I have a string column in my table e.g `status` which contains 2 string values as constants, i am wanting to add the ability so users can update a status only on these 2 string values. The main purpose of the question is am wanting to add validation for the `status` in my controller which the user can only select `online` or `offline` as options

so basically the status column can be these 2 string values

```
  protected $validation = [
        'status' => 'string:online, offline
    ];
```

I know the above doesnt work but i need something similar to validate multiple constant values for the string column.

these are the constants for the status that i need to be using

```
public const ONLINE = 'online';
public const OFFLINE = 'offline';
```

is there a way you can add in validation for the visibility field using these constants? some help would be great.

full class file below:

```
protected $request;

protected $user;


protected $validation = [
    'name' => 'max:10'
];

protected $required = [
    'name'
];

public function __construct(Request $request = null)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

Comment: You can also if you want, replace your constant members by creating an Enum with this package: https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum

Comment: also you can create your own validation with laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the constants to define the possible options:

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$validation = [
        'status' => [Rule::in([Class::ONLINE,Class::OFFLINE])]
    ];
```

Or better, define the constant `STATUSES` listing all the possible statuses in your class

```php
public const STATUS_ONLINE = 'online';
public const STATUS_OFFLINE = 'offline';
public const STATUSES = [self::ONLINE, self::OFFLINE];
```

and use that constant

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$validation = [
        'status' => [Rule::in(Class::STATUSES)]
    ];
```

Comment: does this not define the status as an array? with `[Class::ONLINE,Class::OFFLINE]`

Comment: It does, having it in the Model class is more practical, for example when you add a new status, you just have to add it to the `STATUSES` constant, and no need to cycle through all the form validations you had in place

Comment: does that now mean that `status` will now expect an array instead of a string value 
 this isnt what i want surely if im wanting the result to be a string?

Comment: @lilnoobcoder no, it means the status must be one of the values present in the array (online or offline) and no it doesnt define status as an array. misunderstood what you meant with your first question

Comment: when i add this rule to the validation array i get this error `expression is not allowed as field default value` and the whole array red lines

Comment: @lilnoobcoder can you add tho whole code to your question in an edit section ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207676/discussion-between-n69s-and-lilnoobcoder).

Answer (score 5):

You can use like this in Request class:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'status' => 'in:online,offline'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to check if the string received is one of those two, you could simply do that:

```
protected $validation = [
    'status' => Rule::in(['online', 'offline'])
];
```

[Link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-in) to the documentation.